# PyCharm incompatible bitbucket plugin

Tags: python, pycharm, bitbucket

I am using the PyCharm community edition version 2016.1.2. The Bitbucket plugin currently available from PyCharm's repo browser is not compatible with this version. Has someone found a compatible plugin version somewhere?

Many Thanks in advance!